PostGres DB is read only in pgAdmin despite successful migration into it
I have an old MS Access Database that I want to migrate to a Postgres Db hosted in a Docker environment on a Windows Server.
I want to keep the MS Access Frontend, because it has some Forms and queries that are still needed.
In order to achieve this, I first start my docker container with the following command:
docker run -d --name pg-test -e POSTGRES_DB=testdb -e POSTGRES_USER=testuser -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata -e POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS="--encoding=UTF-8 --lc-collate=C --lc-ctype=C" -v testDbPostGresAnsi:/var/lib/postgresql/data -p 5432:5432 postgres:latest

After that, I use a python script to migrate my Access database to the Postgres Database.
This is the python script:
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect
from sqlalchemy.exc import NoSuchTableError, SQLAlchemyError

# Access database connection parameters
access_db_path = r'Path/To/Db.accdb'
access_conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    rf'DBQ={access_db_path};'
    r'CharacterSet=UTF8;'  # Specify UTF-8 character encoding
)

# PostgreSQL database connection parameters
postgres_db = 'testdb'
postgres_user = 'testuser'
postgres_password = 'test'
postgres_host = 'localhost'
postgres_port = '5432'

# Create PostgreSQL engine
postgres_conn_str = f"postgresql://{postgres_user}:{postgres_password}@{postgres_host}:{postgres_port}/{postgres_db}"
postgres_engine = create_engine(postgres_conn_str)
postgres_inspector = inspect(postgres_engine)

def create_table(table_name, df):
    """Create a table in PostgreSQL if it doesn't exist."""
    df.head(0).to_sql(table_name, postgres_engine, index=True, index_label='id', dtype={'id': sqlalchemy.types.Integer}, if_exists='replace')
    print(f"Table '{table_name}' created in PostgreSQL with UTF-8 encoding.")

def transfer_table_data(access_conn, table_name):
    """Transfer data from an Access table to PostgreSQL."""
    try:
        query = f"SELECT * FROM [{table_name}]"
        df = pd.read_sql_query(query, access_conn)

        if not postgres_inspector.has_table(table_name):
            create_table(table_name, df)

        primary_key = postgres_inspector.get_pk_constraint(table_name)

        if not primary_key['constrained_columns']:
            if 'unique_id' in df.columns:
                df.set_index('unique_id', inplace=True)
                print(f"Using 'unique_id' column as primary key for table '{table_name}'.")
            elif 'id' in df.columns:
                df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
                print(f"Using 'id' column as primary key for table '{table_name}'.")
            else:
                df['id'] = range(1, len(df) + 1)
                df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
                print(f"'id' column created and set as primary key for table '{table_name}'.")

        num_rows = len(df)
        print(f"Transferring {num_rows} rows from table '{table_name}'...")

        if 'unique_id' in df.columns:
            df.to_sql(table_name, postgres_engine, if_exists='replace', index=True, index_label='unique_id')
        else:
            df.to_sql(table_name, postgres_engine, if_exists='replace', index=True, index_label='id')

        print(f"Transferred {num_rows} rows from table '{table_name}' to PostgreSQL.")
    except NoSuchTableError:
        print(f"Table '{table_name}' does not exist in the PostgreSQL database. Creating...")
        create_table(table_name, df)
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while transferring table '{table_name}': {e}")

def main():
    try:
        access_conn = pyodbc.connect(access_conn_str)
        access_cursor = access_conn.cursor()
        access_table_names = [table.table_name for table in access_cursor.tables(tableType='TABLE')]

        for table_name in access_table_names:
            transfer_table_data(access_conn, table_name)

        access_cursor.close()
        access_conn.close()
    except pyodbc.Error as e:
        print(f"An error occurred with the Access database connection: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I also installed the postgres drivers on windows like this:

When the migration is complete, I can open the Postgres database in my PGAdmin and I can see all tables and data. However, editing a data row is impossible in PgAdmin as well as Access DB.
I have no clue what I can try to debug this. Any help on troubleshooting is appreciated.
